# (Seemingly) redundant naming of functions in classes

Tags: javascript, optimization, jit

I've seen various patterns in object creation, but upon diving into some Firefox framework Javascript, I'd noticed that they're using a convention that I haven't seen before and I'm hoping that someone here can either confirm my assumption or correct me:

When building a class, I've done this (and variations of) in the past:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myPublicFunction = function() {
    };
    var myPrivateFunction = function() {
    };
}
```

Bound anonymous functions. Cool. This is what I've seen throughout most frameworks and such.

However, it seem that Mozilla does this:

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myPublicFunction = function MYCLASS_myPublicFunction() {
    };
    var myPrivateFunction = function MYCLASS_myPrivateFunction() {
    };
}
```

My assumption is that in using the latter convention, JS JIT compiles the functions, but wouldn't pick up the first two as they'd be defined at run-time rather than parse time.

Is this assumption correct and if so, does this also apply to other JS engines or just Spidermonkey?

Comment: Its done for readability purposes

Comment: Really? That's *it*? I'm a little disappointed if that's the case. Improving readability by introducing confusion? ;)

Comment: As for your theory, a **J**IT compiler shouldn't give a damn which way a function is defined. My (limited, but above average) knowledge of JIT compilers suggest there's no technical reason for such restrictions.

Comment: @DemianBrecht note also that the function name appears in stack traces. You can take my word for it that `function (anon)` in stack traces induces rage.

Comment: @Raynos: Oohh.. *GOOD* point. Should move that down to be an accepted answer.

Comment: @delnan: That's also what I thought before watching a Google tech talk. Of course, that was Python-specific but thought it may hold true to other languages as well. I'm far from an expert on JITs, but thought it might hold some water in this context.

Comment: @Raynos -- modern browsers have gotten quite good at figuring out a name for anonymous functions in stack traces. This named function pattern is only useful for IE, as far as stack traces go.

Comment: @DemianBrecht I'm interested, do you have a link or at least a paraphrasing of the reasons? But either way, I don't think something like that is to be expected for JS JIT compilers. Given that anonymous functions are abundant and *very* similar to named functions, it seems inexcusable to *not* handle anonymous functions.

Comment: @MattGreer they still can't handler `arr.forEach(function () { })` that function needs a name if you want to debug it sensibly

Comment: @delnan: If I can find the link I'll post it.. I can't remember the specifics but the speaker went into a little detail on how and what gets JIT'ted from py to pyc. All I *really* remember is that it raised an eyebrow. I also agree that it would seem to be inexcusable to not handle anonymous functions.. Was just a theory, however incorrect it proved to be :)

Comment: @Raynos: Seeing a `forEach` that contains an anonymous function for the callback would make me weep a little inside :P

Comment: @DemianBrecht have you seen your average jQuery code? `$(herpderp).bind(function () { })`

Comment: @Raynos: Oh I'm well aware of it unfortunately : /.. Still makes me weep a little.

Comment: @Demian why would that make you weep? An anonymous function for forEach (or an anonymous block in Ruby, etc etc) is probably the most common pattern by far. I'd even say defining a function just to pass to a forEach would make me weep :)

Comment: @MattGreer: Every time you run through an iteration, a new function is created by the interpreter. Smarter way to go about it (imo) is to have a defined function that you just pass into the `forEach`.

Comment: @Demian - that's not true, the function is created before the call to forEach, then passed into forEach. All arguments to a function are resolved before a function executes.

Comment: @MattGreer: I stand corrected (I'm thinking this was a left over assumption created by looking into the tremendously terrible Actionscript 2 VM). I re-read ECMA-262 `forEach` definition and looked into Spidermonkey source and there's nothing re-creating the function. I now feel a little sheep-ish. Thanks for clearing that up for me though.. I don't feel as dirty anymore ;)

Comment: @MattGreer: Altho it *can* be bad (albeit marginally more times than not) if there's a `forEach` within another loop, causing the anonymous function to be created `n` times (I think *that's* what I should have been thinking originally ;))

Comment: @Demian -- yeah, basically anytime your code executes a `function` expression the runtime will create a new function object. So placing a function expression inside a loop will generate that many function objects. That's also a reason why Crockford's module pattern is often not used, as each object gets its own copy of a function. No need to feel sheep-ish, JavaScript is a funky language that has surprised everyone at some point :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reasons to use NFE:

- a function with a name gives more debugging information in your stack trace
- NFE are self documenting. (if you put useful information in the name).

Note that function declarations are better then NFE. (From a personal style choice)

```
function MyClass() {
    this.myPublicFunction = myPublicFunction;

    function myPrivateFunction() {

    }

    function myPublicFunction() {

    }
}
```

Also note that the word "private" is misleading, but that's a tangent.